# C# implementation for training Stanford NLP?

Tags: java, c#, stanford-nlp

I have written a sentiment analysis API using the c# implementation of [Stanford CoreNLP for .NET](http://sergey-tihon.github.io/Stanford.NLP.NET/StanfordCoreNLP.html) but now need to train the model for my requirements.

Has anybody written a c# implementation for building up the train.txt files or running the java command with .NET to process the training files as described [here](https://mailman.stanford.edu/pipermail/java-nlp-user/2013-November/004308.html)

Thanks